# Change Date Index dtype from object to datetime for monthly basis visualisation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, data-science

I am working on a data set which looks like this

```
Index Month Day Year    Temperature in Fahrenheit
0      1    1   2000    77.8
1      1    2   2000    79.3
2      1    3   2000    78.6
3      1    4   2000    78.6
4      1    5   2000    81.1
...   ...   ... ... ...
7299   12   27  2019    79.3
7300   12   28  2019    80.7
7301   12   29  2019    80.1
7302   12   30  2019    77.5
7303   12   31  2019    74.3
```

The types of columns are as follows:

```
Month int64
Day   int64
Year  int64
Temperature in Fahrenheit float64.
```

Now, the problem statement is I want to convert this data to a monthly basis taking mean values across that month days. A snippet is shown below

```
Date
2000-01    78.241935
2000-02    76.510345
2000-03    80.496774
2000-04    84.100000
2000-05    84.841935
             ...    
2019-08    82.912903
2019-09    81.620000
2019-10    84.287097
2019-11    84.236667
2019-12    81.635484
```

I want the Date index(right now of type object) to be of format Datetime so that I can properly visualise them on monthly basis.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

#### `pd.to_datetime`

```
idx = pd.to_datetime(df[['Month', 'Day', 'Year']])
vals = df['Temperature in Fahrenheit'].to_numpy()

pd.Series(vals, idx)

2000-01-01    77.8
2000-01-02    79.3
2000-01-03    78.6
2000-01-04    78.6
2000-01-05    81.1
2019-12-27    79.3
2019-12-28    80.7
2019-12-29    80.1
2019-12-30    77.5
2019-12-31    74.3
dtype: float64
```

You can follow that up with a `resample`

```
pd.Series(vals, idx).resample('M').mean()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way, maybe not as short as @piRSquared

## Coerce Month,Day and Year to string

```
df[['Month', 'Day', 'Year']]=df.iloc[:, 1:-1].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str))
```

## Concat Day, Month and Year and coerce to datetime

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df.pop('Day').str.cat([df.pop('Month'),df.pop('Year')], sep=' '))
```

## Groupby date and mean

```
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)#Set Date as index
df.groupby(df.index.date).agg(TemperatureinFahrenheit= ('TemperatureinFahrenheit','mean'))#Groupby date and mean
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternate way of doing it:

```
data=df.groupby(['Year','Month']).apply(lambda x:x['Temperature in Fahrenheit'].sum()).reset_index()
data['Date']=data['Year']+'-'+data['Month']
data.drop(columns=['Year','Month'],inplace=True)
data['Date']=pd.to_datetime(data['Date'],format='%Y-%-m')
```